# Why does static variable not allow loop() to run?

Tags: c, variables, loops, static

I am writing code for an lamp that mimics the sun (ie rises and sets according to the real sun).

I am trying to use a static variable in the loop in order to keep count of the days since 1/1/12 (the last leap year (366 days))

for some reason, the program only works when the variable is *not* declared as static, but i need the counter to persist through the iteration of each day.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
// Sun Object 

#define REDPIN 5
#define GREENPIN 6
#define BLUEPIN 3

//#define FADESPEED 480// make this higher to slow down
#define FADESPEED 120

void setup() {
  pinMode(REDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREENPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUEPIN, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {

  // daylengths for 4 year's worth of days starting from jan 1 of Great year (366 days) (1/1/2012)
 int dayLengths[] = {33540000,
33540000,
33600000,
// ....
// hundreds of values omitted here
// ....
33360000,
33420000,
33480000,
33480000};


//2012 = 366 days + day # from jan 1st (in 2013)
//starts on 0th day so subtract 1
//ready to go for march 24st @ sunrise

 // why does it not function when day is static?????

     static int day = 449;


  int r, g, b;




   long start = millis();

   for (r = 0; r <256; r++){
     analogWrite(REDPIN, r);
     delay(FADESPEED);
   }

  //analogWrite(REDPIN, 255);

 for (g = 0; g < 230; g++) { 
    analogWrite(GREENPIN, (g*.4));
    delay(FADESPEED*2);

   }

   long stopped = millis();
   long elapsed = stopped - start;
                                          //approx
   // delays (amount of daylight - ( sunrise/sunset time )
 //  delay(dayLengths[day]- (97200*2));

     delay(dayLengths[day]- (elapsed*2));


   for (g = 230; g > 0; g--) { 
    analogWrite(GREENPIN, (g*.4));
    delay(FADESPEED*2);
   }

   for (r = 256; r >0; r--){
     analogWrite(REDPIN, r);
     delay(FADESPEED);
   }

   analogWrite(REDPIN,0);


   //delays (millis in 1 day) - (length of daylight)
   delay(86400000 - dayLengths[day]);



  // once 4 year cycle is over, resets day to 0
   if (day < sizeof(dayLengths  )){

   day++;
   }

   else
   {
   day = 0;

  } 

}
```

Comment: Please tell us what error you are having. What is actually happening when you run the program, or is there a compiler error. If so, what is the error?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is an awful problem description.

Comment: Please try to replicate this problem on a small example. You gave us array of 365+ items, but not a single function definition - so we can't reproduce nor read this code.

Comment: apologies, this is my first post. There is no error, it compiles and uploads successfully. However, the LEDs never turn on.

Comment: I can't say what your whole problem is, but `if (day < sizeof(dayLengths)){` is wrong because `sizeof` is the number of bytes, not the number of entries. You need to divide by the size of the entry: `if (day < sizeof(dayLengths)/sizeof(int)){`

Comment: however, the problem still persists. for some reason, making the day counter static will not allow the loop to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running in an embedded environment, and it's possible that the native hardware has some limitations re: static usage inside the `loop` function.

I already hate myself for suggesting this, but maybe you could try `global` or `global static` usage (i.e. put the `day` variable outside the `loop()` function, either with or without the `static` keyword).  This would give it the scope to live throughout all `loop()` calls...